# Spring postConstruct doesnt load all the messages in the messageSource

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

```
private String message;
@Autowired
private CustomMessageSource   messageSource;
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
   message= messageSource.getMessage("warning-message");
   logger.log(message);
}

@Component
public class CustomMessageSource extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext  ctx;
    public CustomMessageSource() {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
    public String getMessage(String key) {
        return ctx.getMessage(key, new Object[] { }, getCurrentLocale());
    }
}
```

in above code , when @PostConstruct is getting executed,I am getting error:

> messagesource not initialized - call 'refresh' before accessing
>   messages via the context failing the applicationContext loading

warning-message is a key in messages.properties file.

On debugging I have found that even though messageSource object is created but probably messages have not loaded causing this error.

if instead of post construct,I use it directly in the execution methods,it works correctly.
Can some one please throw some light on this if this is even possible or may be I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: How does the MessageSource is declared?  Maybe a @DependsOn might help here...

Comment: @PamStums I have updated question with additional details

Comment: I think, you should add ```@Component``` above  _CustomMessageSource_

Comment: It is already there in my code.had not copied it.i donsee object populated .only thing is the messages are not loaded till then

Comment: I'm guessing that this is an initialization order thing, due to the Spring context not being fully set up yet.  Can you put off what you are doing in the @PostConstruct method until the context is fully created, like in a ContextRefreshedEvent event handler?

Comment: @Steve I am just looking up the message from message sources and storing in the instance variable to reuse it in the class without having to lookup

Comment: @Rips, whatever you are doing, I'm just telling you that you should try doing it later on.  I'm just interpreting what the error you're getting says to me. - whenever you see that message about 'refresh', it's telling you that the context is not consistent.  You often get this message at startup, which means that the context hasn't been completely built yet.